# How to filter out paths containing super nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I have a financial crime dataset stored in Neo4j. It contains things such as people, companies, addresses and sanctioned entities. I'd like to find relationships between companies and sanctioned entities but I'd like to remove paths that include super nodes. The super nodes are often not indicative of a meaningful connection.

I could add some sort of label to the super nodes (see [Shortest paths without supernodes in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052119/shortest-paths-without-supernodes-in-neo4j)) but I'm trying to avoid that. Here's the query I've built to far:

```
MATCH p=(a:LegalEntity)-[*..5]-(s:SanctionedEntity)
WHERE all(n IN nodes(p) WHERE size((n)--()) < 10)
RETURN p
```

It returns the following error message:

> ```
> A pattern expression should only be used in order to test the existence of a pattern. It should therefore only be used in contexts that evaluate to a boolean, e.g. inside the function exists() or in a WHERE-clause. No other uses are allowed, instead they should be replaced by a pattern comprehension. (line 2, column 64 (offset: 115)) "WHERE all(n IN nodes(p) WHERE size((n)--()) < 10)"
> ```

What should I do?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `COUNT` subquery here instead of `size`:

```
MATCH p=(a:LegalEntity)-[*..5]-(s:SanctionedEntity)
WHERE all(n IN nodes(p) WHERE COUNT{(n)--() } < 10)
RETURN p
```

There is also a [dense node APOC function](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.nodes/). I think the threshold for dense nodes in this case is a degree of 50 or more.

```
MATCH p=(a:LegalEntity)-[*..5]-(s:SanctionedEntity)
WHERE all(n IN nodes(p) WHERE NOT apoc.nodes.isDense(n))
RETURN p
```